# Forcing a specific timestamp for files in pythons zipfile

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Is it possible to force a specific timestamp for a file when adding it to a zipfile?

Something along these lines:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
  myzip.write('eggs.txt', date_time=(1752, 9, 9, 15, 0, 0))
```

Can I change the ZipInfo on a member of a zipfile?

Answer (score 12):

Looking at [the source for `ZipFile.write()` in CPython 3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/zipfile.py#L1701), the method always gets its `ZipInfo` by examining the file on disk—including a bunch of metadata like modified time and OS-specific attributes (see [the `ZipInfo.from_file()` source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ea21389dda401457198fb214aa2c981a45ed9528/Lib/zipfile.py#L495)).

So, to get around this limitation, you'll need to provide your own `ZipInfo` when writing the file—that means using [`ZipFile.writestr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) and giving it both a `ZipInfo` and the file data you read from disk, like so:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo
with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip, open('eggs.txt') as txt_to_write:
    info = ZipInfo(filename='eggs.txt',
                   # Note that dates prior to 1 January 1980 are not supported
                   date_time=(1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
    myzip.writestr(info, txt_to_write.read())
```

Alternatively, if you *only* want to modify the `ZipInfo`'s date, you could get it from `ZipInfo.from_file()` and just reset its `date_time` field:

```
info = ZipInfo.from_file('eggs.txt')
info.date_time = (1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

This is better in the general case where you do still want to preserve special OS attributes.

Comment: +1 The problem of having the same hashes for two zip files, where one is created from re-zipping the content of the other, took me 2 hours and I didn't find a solution. Your answer is the solution to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @sema That was exactly my use case as well. I needed to be able to create reproducible ZIPs, such that the ZIP archive would be bit-for-bit identical when created from files with the same contents. Glad I could help someone else. :)